# How to get the coordinates from the address using google map

Tags: flutter, coordinates

I'm trying to get the coordinates from the address which user input,using `flutter_google_places` but here is gives me error

```
 {candidates: [], error_message: You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account, status: REQUEST_DENIED}
```

here is my code

```
static Future<String> getPlaceId(String input) async {
    final String url =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=$input&inputtype=textquery&key$googleApiKey";

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(json);
    var placeId = json['candidates'][0]['place_id'] as String;

    return placeId;
  }
```

i added the key too, but it gives me this error, please help how to do this or this is there any other to get the coordinates from user input address.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps you have to make sure you complete. First, make sure your API key is not restricted for your device. You can either set the key to restrict none or just add your authentic key to the API key. And get the access.

Also basic stuff. Make sure all the needed SDK's are activated for your project. And It would be better if you can provide some more data. That would be kinda helpful. Also don't forget to add your api key to the xml file inside your android project. if you're doing it for android.

(BTW the issue is with your credentials. First solve that. Then you can find the way to get the coordinates. It's pretty easy. You're already there.)

Comment: i added the key in andriod manifest file, followed steps too, but still getting error. what kinda more data you need, let me know?

Comment: Did you check your key?? Is it restricted?? And if it is have you added your credentials there? Or what you can do is make those restrictions to none.